# How to get color scale value (row z-score value) from R pheatmap

Tags: r, heatmap, pheatmap

I have the following data frame:

```r
library(pheatmap)
library(RColorBrewer)

dat <- structure(c(36.28516213, -9.184523335, 5.716034994, 32.82180488, 
-18.5467127, 22.79930301, -24.79075287, -49.23768715), .Dim = c(2L, 
4L), .Dimnames = list(c("motif_a", "motif_b"), c("cow", "dog", 
"snake", "cat")))

dat
#>               cow       dog     snake       cat
#> motif_a 36.285162  5.716035 -18.54671 -24.79075
#> motif_b -9.184523 32.821805  22.79930 -49.23769
```

And with the following heatmap code:

```r
p <- pheatmap(
  dat,
  color = colorRampPalette(rev(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n = 7, name = "RdYlBu")))(1000),
  clustering_method = "ward.D2",
  border_color = "grey60",
  clustering_distance_columns = "correlation",
  clustering_distance_rows = "correlation",
  fontsize_row = 6,
  cluster_rows = TRUE,
  cluster_cols = TRUE,
  scale = "row"
)
```

I can get this plot.

[image]

As noted in the plot how can I get corresponding value for 
every point in the heatmap to the right-hand color scale.

For example, `cow motif_b` has value `-9.184523`, but the right-hand
color scale gives a value between 0 to -0.5. How can I get these values?

The final result is a data frame with the values transformed.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You asked `pheatmap` to plot the Pearson correlation, which is between -1 and 1, when you specified `clustering_distance_xxx = "correlation"`. Run `?pheatmap` for more details.

If you remove those parts from the code, then you'll get what you expected

```r
library(pheatmap)
library(RColorBrewer)

dat <- structure(c(36.28516213, -9.184523335, 5.716034994, 32.82180488, 
    -18.5467127, 22.79930301, -24.79075287, -49.23768715), .Dim = c(2L, 
    4L), .Dimnames = list(c("motif_a", "motif_b"), c("cow", "dog", 
    "snake", "cat")))

myCol <- colorRampPalette(rev(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n = 7, name = "RdYlBu")))(8)

p <- pheatmap(
  dat,
  color = myCol,
  clustering_method = "ward.D2",
  border_color = "grey60",
  clustering_distance_columns = "correlation",
  clustering_distance_rows = "correlation",
  fontsize_row = 6,
  cluster_rows = TRUE,
  cluster_cols = TRUE,
  scale = "row"
)
```

[image]

```r
p1 <- pheatmap(
  dat,
  color = myCol,
  clustering_method = "ward.D2",
  border_color = "grey60"
)
```

[image]

Created on 2018-03-27 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: That's not what I want. I'm want new `dat` with z-score value as coded in right hand-side color scale